# Excess corn starch in a non-newtonian fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I'm currently performing a high school experiment regarding non-newtonian fluid. And as a further exploration, I am aiming to figure out whether excess corn starch in the solution will cause a ball to bounce higher.

Theoretically, excess cornstarch particles will cause the inter-molecular gaps to be reduced and hence causing it to be more solid. However, another paper by my senior states how it became more liquid, which is contradicting to my experimental result.

What I'm asking here is to confirm the theoretical result of placing excess cornstarch, will it cause the non-newtonian to be more solid, or liquid? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"What I'm asking here is to confirm the theoretical result of placing excess cornstarch, will it cause the non-newtonian to be more solid, or liquid?"* I'm a little confused. Confirming (or discrediting) theories is what *experiments* are for.  Do you just want someone to write in strong and confident letters that you are going to get a positive result? If so, why? Negative results are every bit as much part of science as positive ones; indeed they are the thing that distinguished science from less systematic ways of learning how the world behaves.

Comment: Yes, because he (my senior) also experimentally did it, and got different result from I did. Therefore, I was asking what would the theoretical result be. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It's possible that you think the work "theoretical" means something stronger than it does. If one of you has data and the other does not than the argument is over until you can show either than what was measured by the other guy wasn't what is under discussion or you have contradictory data (at which point you start asking how can we get different results with "someone made a mistake" only one of several possible reasons).

Comment: And I know I'm picking on words in a way that may seem pointless. Let me explain why: this site sometimes seems to have a bias toward blackboard physics—possibly because the questions are much more clear cut—and I'm an experimenter so I take many opportunities to emphasize the role of *trying it and seeing* in making this business a science. I don't know much more about non-Newtonian fluids than you can do some cool demos with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a nice review of the subject here](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/466/2116/1201).

At high volume fractions of the corn starch the viscosity is approximately described by the equation:

$$ \eta = \left( 1 - \frac{\varphi}{\varphi_m} \right)^{-B\varphi_m} $$

where $\varphi_m$ and $B$ are experimentally fitted parameters. This known as the  Krieger–Dougherty equation. $\varphi_m$ tells you at what volume fraction the dispersion becomes solid, and it's around the random packing volume fraction. $B$ is of the same order as the Einstein coefficient.

So we expect the viscosity to rise continuously and go to infinity at $\varphi = \varphi_m$. The paper I've linked reports experimental measurements showing that this is what happens.

Note that measuring the viscosity of concentrated suspensions is exceedingly difficult and normally requires specialist kit. At the high viscosities the shear rates are very small so the experiment has to be run for a long time, and the sustension tends to settle on long timescales leading to wall slip and other artefacts.